# Access redis by service name in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I created a redis deployment and service in kubernetes,
I can access redis from another pod by service ip, but I can't access it by service name

the redis yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-deployment
  namespace: myapp-ns
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: redis
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: myapp-ns
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: redis
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
```

Comment: Share logs from coredns pods in kube-system namespace. What is the exact url you are trying?

Comment: Can you edit the question to add the code that's trying to connect to Redis, including the hostname it's using?  What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

I applied your file, and I am able to ping and telnet to the service both from within the same namespace and from a different namespace.  To test this, I created pods in the same namespace and in a different namespace and installed telnet and ping.  Then I exec'ed into them and did the below tests:

*Same Namespace*

```
kubectl exec -it <same-namespace-pod> /bin/bash
# ping redis
PING redis.<redis-namespace>.svc.cluster.local (172.20.211.84) 56(84) bytes of data.

# telnet redis 6379
Trying 172.20.211.84...
Connected to redis.<redis-namespace>.svc.cluster.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

*Different Namespace*

```
kubectl exec -it <different-namespace-pod> /bin/bash
# ping redis.<redis-namespace>.svc.cluster.local
PING redis.test.svc.cluster.local (172.20.211.84) 56(84) bytes of data.

# telnet redis.<redis-namespace>.svc.cluster.local 6379
Trying 172.20.211.84...
Connected to redis.<redis-namespace>.svc.cluster.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If you are not able to do that due to dns resolution issues, you could look at your `/etc/resolv.conf` in your pod to make sure it has the search prefixes `svc.cluster.local` and `cluster.local`

Answer (score 0):

> I created a redis deployment and service in kubernetes, I can access
> redis from another pod by service ip, but I can't access it by service
> name

**Keep in mind that you can use the `Service` name to access the backend `Pods` it exposes only within the same namespace.** Looking at your `Deployment` and `Service` yaml manifests, we can see they're deployed within `myapp-ns` **namespace**. It means that only from a `Pod` which is deployed within this namespace you can access your `Service` by using it's name.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-deployment
  namespace: myapp-ns ### 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: redis
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: myapp-ns ### 
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: redis
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
```

So if you deploy the following `Pod`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis-client
  namespace: myapp-ns ### 
spec:
  containers:
    - name: redis-client
      image: debian
```

you will be able to access your `Service` by its name, so the following commands (provided you've installed all required tools) will work:

```
redis-cli -h redis
telnet redis 6379
```

However if your redis-cliet `Pod` is deployed to completely **different namespace**, you will need to use fully qualified domain name (**FQDN**) which is build according to the rule described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services):

```
redis-cli -h redis.myapp-ns.svc.cluster.local
telnet redis.myapp-ns.svc.cluster.local 6379
```